# DateAdd - SQL expression

Tags: sql, expression

I am trying to create an expression with SQL. The expression value is trying to assign a value to the days of the week. Sunday is 1 through to Saturday which is 7. I am then trying to add 5 days if it is a Monday so that it lands on a Friday otherwise every other day add 7 days. E.g.

```
WeekDay Inlist("2",",") DateAdd(5, "d") OR ds WeekDay Inlist("1,3,4,5,6,7",",") DateAdd(7, "d")
```

However this does not seem to work?
So basically I enter my date in a databox as 15/03/2017 which is a Wednesday,
Our expression would say if its a Monday to add 5 days and therefore result in false. Because its a Wednesday we would need to say add 7 days, this ignores Saturday and Sunday and therefore would result in True. This would land on the following Wednesday.

Any ideas? :D

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL at all... Show us more code.

Comment: It is a value from a databox expression. You enter the data from a databox

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which variation of SQL you're using, but there's likely an equivalent to the T-SQL CHOOSE() and DATEPART() functions in most variants that will do this.

The expression syntax could end up something like this:

```
DATEADD(CHOOSE(DATEPART("dw", date), 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), "d", date)
```

Comment: T-SQL: Error: Variable or method date was not found  at position 35

Comment: You need to replace "date" with whatever your date field is called.

Comment: DATEADD(CHOOSE(DATEPART("dw", {Script.Details01}), 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), "d", {Script.Details01})

Error: Variable or method DATEPART was not found  at position 42

Comment: Are you Using MS SQL Server

Comment: Nope I am using a third party software which uses T-SQL